# Objective c - proper way to set subview frame so it will fill the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewController inside of a `navigationController`, the view controller has a tableview.
In `viewDidLoad` I set the tableview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // init tableView
    CGRect tableFrame = self.view.bounds;

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}
```

The problem with this code is that the table view frame is not correct - the height is 460 and I need it to be 416.

[The iPhone screen height is 480, minus the status bar (20) minus the navigation bar (44) = 416]

So what is the proper way to set the table view so it will fill the screen?
I can think of two ways:

1. set its frame to = `(0, 0, 320, 416)`
2. use: `[_tableView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use magic numbers. Use the resizing flags correctly.
So yes, your 2. approach is correct.

1) Use the superviews bounds.
`_tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;`;

2) Set autoresizing flags
 `[_tableView setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];`

(you did all of this already :)

Answer (score 6):

Number 1 is absolutely the wrong way to do it... what happens if the screen size changes in a future OS / device?

I'm curious why you're not doing this using a nib file, and saving yourself the trouble, but if you must do it in code, set the auto-resizing mask per your option 2.